# how to subtract decimals in dev c++

Tags: math, decimal, dev-c++

I'm a beginner and I need to know how to work with decimals

My english is very limited however I will try my best to make sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(){
    float a, b, c, d, e, f;
    scanf ("%f%f", &a, &b);
    c=a/b; 
    d=a/b;
    e=c-d
    printf ("%.0f rounded", c);
    printf ("%f answer", d);
    printf ("%f decimal", e);
    
    }
```

I am a beginner, I have only written VERY simple codes (simple addition, subtraction, writing texts, etc)

I want this code to be able to receive 2 numbers (dividend, divisor) and then give me 2 answers, (one's a whole number, the other one is a decimal)

For example, if I were to write 11 for

````
a
``` and 2 for
````

b

```
"5" and "0.5" instead of "5.50"


I'm able to get the rounded numbers and the exact answer, so I thought I could subtract these two, but I don't know how to make the code save the 2 answers it has given me and subtract them.

(Running the above code, and inputting 11 and 2 I receive "6" and "5.50000", now in order to get "0.50000" I need to subtract "5.50000" from "6" but I don't know how to make the program save the answers it has given me)

Am I on the right track? Or is there a much easier way to do what I want to do?


Thank you for taking your time to read this, any and all suggestions would be helpful. ^^
```

Comment: `c` and `d` are the same value right now. You're only _printing_ it as decimal vs. integer (or rather, rounded decimal). So you'll need to explicitly cast one of those two to an integer, otherwise `e` will always be zero (because `c-d`, when they're the same value, is only ever zero).

Comment: google `floor,ceil` functions (from `math.h`) ... for example try `a = floor(x); b = x-a;` ... where `x` is some value and `a,b` are its parts before and after decimal point beware if `x` is negative you might want to check the result if it behaves like you want (its usually confusing for rookies)

Comment: Try  `printf ("%.0g rounded", trunc(c));  printf ("%g answer", c - trunc(c));  printf ("%g decimal", c);`.